# .NET Reflection - Inspecting Type info and retrieving Attributes performance

Tags: c#, .net, performance, reflection, attributes

I saw many articles about .NET Reflection performance, and I know that invoking the methods and retrieving the properties values using reflection is performance costly and it's about 2x-3x slower then direct calls.

But what about Type information and Attributes? I know that Types metadata is cached in .NET...so I think it's shouldn't be performance costly and it's something similar to searching in dictionaries or in lists (But I'm not sure)...
How slow is inspecting the Type information to check the Type of properties and getting Custom Attributes for properties types?

Does it bad practice and design to make many things to work based on attributes?

What I want to do, is to create some infrastructure for ASP.NET, that will inspect many controls and types for Custom Attributes in order to retrieve the information about required JavaScript files and client code that should be registered on page.

Comment: How does it perform compared to what? For retrieving property values, invoking methods, etc. there is a clear difference between doing that with reflection, and doing that without reflection. But you can't say "getting type information with reflection is slower than without reflection", since you can't get that without reflection.

Comment: Even if reflection is slower than non-reflection code, in general it's still pretty fast. If you're going to only be using to to inspect attributes on ASP.NET pages as part of the request-response lifecycle, then I seriously doubt you're going to have any _measurable_ performance impact of using reflection in this way, so go to town. Performance issues _generally_ crop up when you're hitting reflection many hundreds or thousands of times per second in tight loops. In the end, your mileage will vary and I suggest you test and make sure you don't have performance issues.

Comment: @hvd I understand, but does it will be much slower that if I will make this using OOP (Interfaces/Abstract and so on)...it may work to, but then my infrastructure will be much less flexible...

Comment: @AlexDn: Since this is just ASP.NET request-response stuff, I suggest you go with the flexible/maintainable infrastructure. I doubt you'll get major performance impacts from it (just the network communication alone will be far longer than anything you'll probably do with reflection). If you end up building a service where the reflection becomes a _measurable_ issue, well, then you're probably getting enough traffic/usage of your system that this will be a _good_ problem to have. :)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair currently our application handles about two thousand ASPX requests per minute, and each page can have about 100-200 controls overall...of course I will not check each control for attributes (i think about 10% of them), do you think it still will be not measurable? Thanks.

Comment: For better or for worse, there are quite a lot of corners in the .NET world that rely heavily on reflection, so in many cases you're already using it. We're at the point where many people are making the choice to sacrifice some numerical performance for engineering convenience and/or future flexibility-- assuming of course that decision still gets you acceptable performance. But I second those saying you should simply try it and test its impact. Also bear in mind that the results of reflection can be cached.

Comment: Heh, maybe I spoke too soon then. I would still bet money that it won't be an issue, but definitely at that scale I would suggest you A) measure some benchmarks of current performance, B) try implementing it, C) test it and measure new benchmarks. If performance does suffer greatly, double-check/debug to make sure it isn't just an implementation issue that can be optimized/fixed. EDIT: Oh, and also, even _if_ performance dips, remember that before you go and optimize it or throw it out, first _upgrade your server hardware_! Often that's the simplest/easiest/best step!

Comment: @AlexDn You should be able to cache a lot of the information, and avoid recalculating it on every request. If you get that right, you won't need ~40000 checks per minute, and it shouldn't make a measurable impact on performance. (But if you don't get that right, I really don't know how well reflection will perform.)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair will invest many of budget in hardware, so the IT infra is good enough and there shouldn't be the problem to get more, but before, the existing assets should be used efficiently :)) Anyway much thanks for feedback, I think I should try that way!

Comment: @hvd that is what I would like to know...if ~40000 scans for types meta data will make measurable difference in performance, before I will do it using cache...it shouldn't be so hard to implement (depends on cache complexity - Attributes instances may be mutable in my plans and types inheritance is involved to), but it still will take some time :) Anyway thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Building an architecture based on attribute is not a bad thing, but if you want to keep flexibility, you have to introduce an interface/implementation to provide these informations programatically independent to attributes and define a default implementation based on attributes.

Reading attributes is not slow but if you care about micro-optimization you can create your own cache like this :

```
static public class Metadata<T>
{
    static public readonly Type Type = typeof(T); //cache type to avoid avcessing global metadata dictionary

    static public class Attribute<TAttribute>
        where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
            static public readonly TAttribute Value = Metadata<T>.Type.GetCustomAttributes(Metadata<TAttribute>.Type).SingleOrDefault() as TAttribute; 
    }
}

//usage
Metadata<MyType>.Attribute<MyAttributeType>.Value; //exception if more then once and null if not defined.
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll get the best answer if you profile your use cases directly. A little reflection isn't bad, after all. A lot of reflection can be. Use the `Stopwatch` class to time your alternatives.